# Use LINQ to get Child items from one List<>, that are referenced in a second List<>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.7 application.

Given are 2 Tables:

```
Table Parent Group
------------------
1    | A
2    | B
3    | C
4    | D

Table Child Group
-----------------
 1  |  3 = Id from Parent Group
 1  |  4 = Id from Parent Group
```

In my C# I get 2 classes, which are stored into lists:

```
public class ParentGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildGroup
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

After all I query 2 lists:

```
List<ParentGroup> allGroupElements;

List<ChildGroup> childGroupElements;
```

Now I need to design a LINQ query that queries all Child Elements according to the parent Id within a method.

I thought I first iterate over all ParentElements to retrieve the children, something like this:

```
foreach(var item in allGroupElements){
   // ... I need to query all children according to a parentId
}
```

Do you know how to use a LINQ query to retrieve all Child Elements with the Id of the Parent Group? And store them somehow into a new structure?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need them recursively? So if item 1 is parent of item 2 and item 2 is parent of item 3, the result for 1 would be 2 and 3? Or only 2?

Comment: A good way to find the right LINQ method(s) to accomplish a task is to first figure out how to implement a solution _without_ LINQ to conceptualize how it should work.  So how do you think you might do that here with a `foreach` loop?  You show one in your code but the body is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just use .Where in your loop

```
foreach(var item in allGroupElements){
   var children = childGroupElements.Where(c => c.ParentId == item.Id);
}
```

Or you can .GroupBy, then use them

```
var allChildrenByParentId = children.GroupBy(c => c.ParentId);
```

Or you could use .Join, if you wanted parent and children in the same collection...

Answer (score 0):

Use a join like this :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ParentGroup> allGroupElements = new List<ParentGroup>() {
                new ParentGroup() { Id = 1, Name = "A"},
                new ParentGroup() { Id = 2, Name = "B"},
                new ParentGroup() { Id = 3, Name = "C"},
                new ParentGroup() { Id = 4, Name = "D"}
            };

            List<ChildGroup> childGroupElements = new List<ChildGroup>() {
                new ChildGroup() {  ChildId = 1, ParentId = 3},
                new ChildGroup() {  ChildId = 1, ParentId = 4}
            };


            var groups = (from all in allGroupElements
                          join child in childGroupElements on all.Id equals child.ParentId
                          select new { all = all, child = child })
                         .ToList();

        }
    }
    public class ParentGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildGroup
    {
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public int ChildId { get; set; }
    }
```